# Redirect from server without affecting browser history

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, express

I am using NodeJS and express. Now, whenever user posts something on an endpoint/page, I am taking the data and send back a 302 via response.redirect() to the same page to avoid the user accidentally reposting data.
However, the problem arises with the back history. Even if the url is *exactly* the same, the browser seems to put it into history (tested with latest chrome) and posting a few times to the page then going back let's me go to the same page the same amount of time which I of course want to avoid. How to do that?